# How can I make .filter work properly on React-Native?

Tags: javascript, json, react-native

I'm trying to display this info on a **FlatList** once app is loaded, having an input where I can query an item that I would like to check then display it on the same FlatList. The issue is that data={objects.filter(...)} is not working properly, I already received data on **console.log('data: ', data)**; it should be passing the info to **objects** through **setObjects** but I think it is not doing it, what could I be missing??

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Text , TextInput, View, StyleSheet, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import  Object  from './Object';


export default function Content () {
  const [objects, setObjects] = useState([]);
    const [refreshing, setRefreshing] = useState(false);
    const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
  
  const loadData = async () => {
        const res = await fetch(
            "https://us.api.blizzard.com/data/wow/search/item?namespace=static-us&name.en_US=Thunderfury&orderby=id&_page=1&access_token=(private token)"
        );
        const data = await res.json();
    console.log('data: ', data);
        setObjects(data);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        loadData();
    }, []);
 
  
  return (
      <View style={styles.content}>
      <View style={styles.section} >
        <Text style={styles.logo}>Input </Text>
        <TextInput
                    style={styles.searchInput}
                    placeholder="Search an item"
                    placeholderTextColor="#858585"
                    onChangeText={(text) => text && setSearch(text)}
                />
        </View>

        
        <FlatList
                    data={objects.filter(
                    (object) =>
                        object.name.en_US.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLocaleLowerCase()) 
                )}
                showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
                renderItem={({ item }) => <Object object = {item} style={styles.item}/>}
                refreshing={refreshing}
                onRefresh={loadData()}
            />
       
      </View>
     
  );
}
```

Comment: What happens when you `console.log(objects)`? That should tell you if setObjects is working.

Comment: console.log(objects)  returns  "objects is not defined"

also I am getting the info I need on console.log('data: ', data);  

{
    "page": 1,
    "pageSize": 5,
    "maxPageSize": 100,
    "pageCount": 1,
    "results": [
        {
            "key": {
                "href": "https://us.api.blizzard.com/data/wow/item/19019?namespace=static-9.2.5_43810-us"
            },
            "data": {
                "level": 29,
                "required_level": 25,
         
            }
        }
    ]
}